# Hadoop3: worker node error connecting to ResourceManager

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, hadoop-streaming

I have a 3 node hadoop cluster (DigitalOcean droplets):

- hadoop-master is configured as both namenode and datanode
- hadoop-worker1 and hadoop-worker2 are configured as datanodes

Whenever I run a mapreduce streaming job and a worker node gets selected to run the ApplicationMaster the job hangs as it tries to connect to the ResourceManager. The datanode log shows it tries to connect to 0.0.0.0

```
INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8030
INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8030. Already tried 0 time(s);
INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8030. Already tried 1 time(s);
```

That is the default value of the `yarn.resourcemanager.hostname property`.
However I have specified this property in yarn-site.xml for both of my worker nodes:

```
<property>
   <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
   <value>hadoop-master</value>
</property>
```

And on all my nodes, my /etc/hosts file looks like this, so hadoop-master should point to the correct IP address.

```
#127.0.1.1 hadoop-worker1 hadoop-worker1
127.0.0.1 localhost

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
#::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
#fe00::0 ip6-localnet
#ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
#ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
#ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
#ff02::3 ip6-allhosts

165.22.19.161 hadoop-master
165.22.19.154 hadoop-worker1
165.22.19.158 hadoop-worker2
```

I also checked the configurations by going to hadoop-worker1:9864 and accessing the web interface of the worker node to see what was loaded:

```
<property>
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
<value>hadoop-master</value>
<final>false</final>
<source>yarn-site.xml</source>
</property>
```

Even more, I tried running a YARN command from one of the workernodes and it can actually contact the ResourceManager correctly:

```
hadoop@hadoop-worker1:/opt/hadoop$ yarn node --list
2019-06-15 18:47:42,119 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at hadoop-master/165.22.19.161:8032
Total Nodes:3
         Node-Id             Node-State Node-Http-Address       Number-of-Running-Containers
hadoop-worker2:40673            RUNNING hadoop-worker2:8042                                0
hadoop-worker1:41875            RUNNING hadoop-worker1:8042                                1
hadoop-master:40075             RUNNING hadoop-master:8042                                 0
hadoop@hadoop-worker1:/opt/hadoop$
```

I am unsure what to do, I believe it might have something to do with streaming jobs not correctly loading the settings, any help would be appreciated as I have been stuck on this issue for 2 days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added the `-D yarn.resourcemanager.hostname=hadoop-master` flag to the mapred streaming command and it seems to work now.